# pgRouting gives fragmented results when trying to calculate route

Tags: pgrouting

I have a road network and I used `pgr_createTopology` and `pgr_nodeNetwork` to convert it for use in pgRouting library. However the results are fragmented and there is no continuous path. Furthermore I have to give source and target values instead of ID in the below query. here `747` and `311` are source and target values from table rather than IDs.

`pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT id, source::int, target::int, length::double precision AS cost FROM guru_noded', 
    747, 311, false, false);`

I am new to this.

Answer (score 3):

Probabaly your "snapping tolerance" parameter did not match with the unit of your data, when you ran `pgr_createTopology`.

The dimension of the tolerance parameter depends on your data projection. Usually it’s either “degrees” or “meters”.

Comment: Are u saying that if I have my data in wgs84 lat long coordinate system, and run pgr_createtopology with tolerance parameter value 0.001, then 0.001 will be considered as degrees instead of meters?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The snapping value is in the unit of your projection.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried another solution?

If you just want to calculate the faster or shorter path, just use the network analysis tool from QGIS

http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/pt_PT/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html